# Images being upscaled in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I have images stored as blobs in SQLite. Other tools like DB Browser for SQLite show the images themselves are not upscaled.

I scaled them down from an original image with the following code.

```
final thumbnailData = encodeJpg(copyResize(
  decodeImage(imageData),
  width: 400,
  interpolation: Interpolation.average
));
```

When displayed in Flutter they are noticably upscaled.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Image.memory(_getThumbnailData());
}
```

`Image.memory()` has a `scale` argument that defaults to `1.0`. Setting it manually to be sure doesn't help either.

I have to set it to some guesstimated value like `2.0` to get the correct scale but I don't understand why and wether `2.0` is actually "unscaled" or still slightly off.

How can I tell Flutter to display the images as they are?

Comment: just for clarification; are trying saying that for example a 400 x 400 image get's displayed as 800 x 800??

Comment: Yes, a screenshot from the emulator is 1080 pixel wide. The image is 400 pixel wide and displayed as something like 800 pixel (almost the whole screen) and is therefore terribly upscaled. The same for a 200 pixel wide image which looks upscaled to 400 pixel.

Comment: flutter uses logical pixel instead of hardware pixel. So, 400x400 image may get displayed differently based on the device display density.

Comment: Thanks, "logical pixels" led me to `MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio`. Using that as the `scale` property for `Image.memory()` displays the image properly.

Comment: That's great. may I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter uses logical pixel instead of physical pixels.

> Device pixels are also referred to as physical pixels. Logical pixels are also referred to as device-independent or resolution-independent pixels.

### How to convert between physical pixels and logical pixels?

To convert between physical pixels and logical pixels, you can use [devicePixelRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Window/devicePixelRatio.html).

> The number of device pixels for each logical pixel. This number might not be a power of two. Indeed, it might not even be an integer. For example, the Nexus 6 has a device pixel ratio of 3.5.

```
MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio
```